# Remove scientific notation bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, arithmetic, floating-point

When I convert MB to GB I'm getting below output. I want this output in normal format. When I use `bc` I'm getting an error. The text file contains nearly 100 such lines like this.

I want to print this in normal output, (without notation):

```
1.14441e-07
4.95911e-07
3.05176e-07
1.90735e-07
3.05176e-07
```

Commands:

```
$ DIVISOR=104857600
$ sudo  du --max-depth=1 /home/xxx | tail -1 | \
      awk -v DIVISOR=104857600 '{print $1/DIVISOR}'
1.14441e-07
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`awk` has a sprintf function, which gives you access to the printf "f" format specifier.

```
echo  .123456 | awk '{ print sprintf("%.9f", $1); }'
```

produces

```
0.123456000
```

Comment: Sweet, this worked for me with RRDTool, which really likes to give scientific notation (e.g. 1404784800: 7.8472672909e+01) output.

Answer (score 5):

To control the formatting of the output you can use `printf` either directly from `awk` or directly via the shell.

However you can also control the output directly using `du`. For example you can specify `-h` to output the results in human readable formats.

#### Examples

```
$ du -h --max-depth=1 /home/saml/apps | tail -1
9.0G    /home/saml/apps

$ du -h --max-depth=1 /home/saml/apps/gCAD3D  | tail -1
1.1M    /home/saml/apps/gCAD3D
```

#### Formatting using printf

But as you've noticed you lose resolution with this method. So if you truly want to keep a higher degree of resolution, you're forced to take the values from `du` at a lower level, and then format the output to fit which ever higher level units you want.

#### Example

In MB's using `du`.

```
$ du -m --apparent-size --max-depth=1 /home/saml/apps | tail -1
8916    /home/saml/apps
```

Using `awk` + `printf`.

```
$ DIVISOR=10487600
$ du --apparent-size --max-depth=1 /home/saml/apps | \
      tail -1 | awk -v D=$DIVISOR '{printf "%.9f\n", $1/D}'
0.870499638
```

You can control the amount of precision you want by changing the argument to `printf`. Here's 5 places.

```
$ DIVISOR=10487600
$ du --apparent-size --max-depth=1 /home/saml/apps | \
      tail -1 | awk -v D=$DIVISOR '{printf "%.5f\n", $1/D}'
0.87050
```

Notice that it takes care to round it correctly where ever you decide to cut off the precision.