# Display integral in scientific notation?

Tags: bash, shell-script, floating-point

I have an integral value:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
2400000
```

I assign it to a shell variable:

```
CPU_FREQ=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq)
```

I want to display it in scientific format from within a shell script using bash. In addition, I need to use it as an argument to a program. Here's what I want:

```
echo $CPU_FREQ
2.4+1e9
```

There are some hits on the web, but its not obvious to me how to modify them because I usually work with C/C++/Objective C. See, for example, [bash display integral in scientific notation](http://www.google.com/search?q=bash+print+integral+in+scientific+notation) and [Remove scientific notation bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104332).

Is there a way to convert an integral into scientific notation?

Or how do I display the value scientific notation?

Comment: `printf "%e\n" "$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq)"`

Comment: @jww `2.4+1e9` does not make sense here (it would be equal to `1000000002.4`). Do you mean `2.4e+6`?

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as:

```
printf "%g" $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq)
```

Or, using perl:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq | perl -e 'printf("%g\n", <>)'
```

The format you're requesting seems a bit strange, but these two examples will print a number using scientific notation.

Comment: *"The format you're requesting seems a bit strange"* - Why? The benchmark program requires scientific notation. If I use an integral, then it makes the benchmark program think the CPU speed is 10^18 rather than 10^9.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed as @Jan mentioned, you can use printf with %e. @Will mentioned the option %g, but that's not necessarily scientific notation (see below).

It's based on C's printf that you already know.

```
CPU_FREQ=$(printf "%e" $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq))
```

printf command works like this:

```
var=1
printf "print a float variable %f, or an integer literal. %d" $var 2
```

You can use either %g, %e, %G or %E.
also, with optional extra literal integer parameters a,b, e.g.: %a.bf

Briefly, 
the optional paramater a is the minimum width size (which are ignored if forwarding the output in a variable).

%.be prints it with exactly b decimals, rounding of padding with zeros if necessary.
%.bg prints the result with b significant figures, ignoring all trailing zeros. (It can also be thought as the shorter between %f and %e two, but is it worth noticing again, it is without trailing zeros.)

Examples:

```
R=10000001
printf "%e\n"  $R
1.000000e+07
printf "%g\n" $R
1e+07

R=1.0000001 
printf "%e\n"  $R
1.000000e+00
printf "%g\n" $R
1

R=1000000.1    
printf "%e\n"  $R
1.000000e+06
printf "%g\n" $R
1e+06

R=.10000001
printf "%e\n"  $R
1.000000e-01
printf "%g\n" $R 
0.1
```

(%G and %E are just like %g and %e, but they print the output in upper case instead, which only applies to the e that turns into an E.)